# Get absolute position of just added view

Tags: android, layout, view, position

i read tons of threads here, but none helps.

I am adding view to vertical linear layout and i need to get absolute position of that view.

my code:

```
parent.addView(ll);
parent.recomputeViewAttributes(ll);
parent.invalidate();
ll.invalidate();
int[] p = new int[2];
ll.getLocationOnScreen(p);
Log.d("test",""+p[1]);
```

And when i add several views i always get same number:

```
D/test: 355
D/test: 355
D/test: 355
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Every time are you creating a new view, or adding that same view?

Comment: I am creating new view, expected output should be something like that: 355, 400, 445... I see on my phone, how new view is added by clicking on button and every new view has larger "y" coordinate.